# How to add data grouped week by week to a database?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, orm, sqlalchemy

I am attempting to write a program that should handle a small part of my personal budget. I need to add data to a database that is handled somewhat like this:

```
Week of 1/1/19 -> [[1/1/19, Walmart, 13.43], [1/2/19, Walgreens, 10.54]]
Week of 1/7/19 -> [[1/7/19, Taco Bell, 24.12]]
...
```

Basically after a new week, a new "Week of" entry will be created with sub-entries within that. I am stuck on how to create the "Week of" entries and how to add entries within that week.
What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would keep the data in a flat database format and only summarise or group by week when you need to. That way, adding or deleting individual transactions is easy.

Using Pandas, you would do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame([['1/1/19', 'Walmart', 13.43], ['1/2/19', 'Walgreens', 10.54], ['1/7/19', 'Taco Bell', 24.12]], columns=['Date', 'Payee', 'Value'])

data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date']
data['Week'] = data['Date'].dt.weekofyear

data
#      Date      Payee  Value  Week
# 0  1/1/19    Walmart  13.43     1
# 1  1/2/19  Walgreens  10.54     1
# 2  1/7/19  Taco Bell  24.12     2

data.groupby(by='Week').sum()
#       Value
# Week       
# 1     23.97
# 2     24.12
```

Comment: This is genius. I have no idea why I was choosing to go with SQLAlchemy when this is more straightforward. I do have a question though: say I have a set spending amount per week, how would I "set" this default limit and subtract from the limit depending on how much was spent in each individual entry?

Comment: What do you suggest? @closetCoder (forgot to mention your name)